# Bokeh VBar chart data not populating

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am looking to create a VBar chart with a select widget in Bokeh.  Prior to adding the Select widget I am just trying to populate a VBar with a single tech firm.  When I execute the below code, I get the figure output as expected with the correct title and axis titles and colors etc, but there is no data populated.  What am I missing?

```
#Hist
b_hist = figure(title="Tech Data", 
                tools=["save, wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset"], 
                background_fill_color = "white")
#title formatting
b_hist.title.align = "center"
b_hist.title.text_color = "midnightblue"
b_hist.title.text_font_size = '18pt'

#axis title formatting
b_hist.yaxis.axis_label = "Millions"
b_hist.xaxis.axis_label = "Quarters"
b_hist.xaxis.axis_label_text_color = "midnightblue"
b_hist.yaxis.axis_label_text_color = "midnightblue"
b_hist.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
b_hist.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'

one_name = tech_firms[tech_firms['Company Name']=="Apple"]

b_hist.vbar(x = one_name.QTR, top = one_name.PROFIT, width=0.9)

show(b_hist)
```

### Example Data in one_name:

[image: Mock Data]

```
print(one_name.dtypes)
```

yields `PROFIT = int64, Company Name = object, QTR = object`

Comment: A simple `p = figure(); p.vbar(x=10, top=20, width=0.9)` works fine for me, so it's something about the parts you have not included. Can you provide a *complete* minimal example?

Comment: Hi @bigreddot the only thing I left out was the loading of tech_firms df, which has proprietary datasets in it, but I verified one_name via print(one_name) and it includes all columns (most importantly the PROFIT and QTR columns).

Comment: @bigreddot Ah wait a minute, does the x axis require numeric values?  Or can it include strings?

Comment: What are the types? Are `one_name.QTR` string names? Then you need to create a categorical range. If you can't share real data, mock something. People want to help but need complete information.

Comment: There is an entire chapter of the users guide dedicated just to handling categorical (string) data: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: Yes, they're strings.  Thank you for that link I will take a look now.  I, for some reason, was unable to find that earlier when searching for it.  I'll revert back shortly.  I'll add a mock data range above.  You're right that would (obviously) be helpful.  Sorry for not including earlier

Comment: @bigreddot Added examples of what data is found in the tech_firms df as well as the data types obtained by one_name.dtypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using categorical values on axes, you have to inform Bokeh what the values are, and what order you want them to appear in on the axis (it has no way to guess your intentions). Typically, something like:

```
p = figure(..., x_range=sorted(df.QTR.unique())
```

Passing that as `x_range` will sort the unique `QTR` values lexicographically on the x-axis, but you can put them in whatever order you need.